# Unix retry logic to fetch the password

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In my unix shell script I am trying to fetch the password logic for 3 times.

Sometime this password not retrieving. after retrying couple of time its retrieving the password and store in password variable.

I tried with for loop but its every time failing and not assigning to password variable.

my logic :

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do 
    "cmd=(""`ssh -i ~/ server "")" && s=0 && break || s=$? && sleep 15; 
done; (exit $s)
```

Answer (score 1):

The extra quotes around `cmd=$(""`ssh -i ~/ password server "")` are causing syntax problems. The quotes should just be around the command substitution.

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do 
    password=$(ssh -i ~/ password server)
    s=$?
    if [[ $s -eq 0 ]]
    then 
        echo "$password"
        break
    fi
    sleep 15
done
exit $s
```

Comment: Great thanks. Its works for me. I added the else loop for message if not retrieved from loop. thanks